# Set Default user when EnsureUser fails

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, user-accounts

I made the following Powershell script to check if a user exists in Sharepoint 2013:

```
$siteCollUrl = "http://my-sharepoint-site"

$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $siteCollUrl;

$test_user = "CONTOSO\Administrator"
$userx = $spSourceWeb.EnsureUser($test_user)
    if ($userx -eq $null) {
       echo "default user" 
    } else {
     echo $userx.UserLogin
    }
```

When a user does not exists Powershell gives me an exception:

> User can not be  found

Instead of the exception I want to use the if/else loop to set a default user (see code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a try/catch block like this:

```
$siteCollUrl = "http://my-sharepoint-site"

$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $siteCollUrl;

$test_user = "CONTOSO\Administrator"
try {
    $userx = $spSourceWeb.EnsureUser($test_user)
    echo $userx.UserLogin
} catch {
    echo "default user" 
}
```